# Is there a Windows Form control that simulates SelectCheckBoxMenu control of Primefaces?

Tags: winforms, user-interface, controls

Two year ago, I have developped a Java `J2EE` application using `Primefaces` widget.

Now, I develop an application using `VB.Net` using `WinForms`.

I search to use a widget that is equivalent to `SelectCheckBoxMenu` written by `Primefaces` for Web development [www.primefaces.org/showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/checkboxMenu.xhtml?jfwid=6548a)

The particularity of this control is that it allows adding multiple keys from a ComboBox widget.

Example:

[image]

Do this control exist for WinForms ?

What is its name ?

Comment: I would call it a `ComboCheckBox`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622338/combobox-with-checkbox-in-winforms

Comment: Yes it is as a ComboCheckBox; but it is also more powerful because TextBox can grow automatically and TextPort part can contain directly removable rectangles as Paris followed by a X that alllows to remove it directly.

Comment: At Telerik, what I search is a Multi-Column ComboBox. But Telerik element seems to be not growable ! And Telerik is not free !